# Use PHP to shuffle list and create random value for form input then validate?

Tags: php

I understand the name of this question is a little vague, not sure how to phrase it short enough but here is my question: I have a form, and at the end of the form I want to add an input that asks the user (for example) what `1 + 7` is, and the only accepted value can be `8` - except I want to use `PHP` to randomize the number between `2 and 9` on page load, how do I go about doing that?

Here is the input:

```
<label>What is $question?
<input type="text" id="human" placeholder="What is it?"></label>
```

The way I picture this I see two end variables, one being the question and the other being the answer. There would be a series of questions with the appropriate answers that would be shuffled on page load. Like `1+1, 1+2, 1+3, 4+4, 3+6, etc...` and the `PHP` would have some fun with that in the background before a bot can determine what the value is.

I can sort of read `PHP`, I just don't know where to start when writing it. All help is appreciated!

---

Based on what you gave me for the above answer, this is what I've come up with for the alternate code I'm using here (it obviously doesn't work though haha):

EDIT: I actually got it working, you can view the working code below... but if you could take a look and polish it that would be awesome =)

```
<div>
    <div><label id="question-label"><span data-tooltip class="has-tip tip-top" title="This is how we know you're actually human!" id="question-tip-f"><span id="question-f"></span>?</span> <span class="star">*</span></label></div>
    <div><input type="text" id="human-f" placeholder="What is it?"></div>
</div>

<script>
var num1 = Math.floor( Math.random()*9 ) + 1,
    num2 = Math.floor( Math.random()*9 ) + 1,
    result = num1 + num2;
document.getElementById( 'question-f' ).innerHTML = num1 + ' + ' + num2;
document.getElementById( 'form-footer' ).addEventListener( 'submit', function(e) {
    var el = document.getElementById( 'human-f' );
    var ql = document.getElementById( 'question-tip-f' );
    if ( el.value != result ) {
        ql.parentNode.setAttribute( "class", 'error' );
        e.preventDefault();         
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple client side example. I generates random numbers and prevents form submission if the field is blank or has wrong value. PHP solution is more bullet proof, and will involve sessions, similar as captcha.

```
<form id="myform" action="index.php" method="post">
    <label>What is <span id="question"></span>
    <input type="text" id="human" placeholder="What is it?"/></label>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
    var num1 = Math.floor( Math.random()*9 ) + 1,
        num2 = Math.floor( Math.random()*9 ) + 1,
        result = num1 + num2;

    document.getElementById( 'question' ).innerHTML = num1 + ' + ' + num2;

    document.getElementById( 'myform' ).addEventListener( 'submit', function(e) {
        var el = document.getElementById( 'human' );
        if ( el.value != result ) {
            el.parentNode.setAttribute( "class", 'error' ); // add .error class to label
            e.preventDefault();         
        }
    });
</script>
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6628/)**

---

#### EDIT: The PHP solution.

The statement

> PHP solution is more bullet proof, and will involve sessions, similar as captcha.

in my original answer is ambiguous. While writing that I forgot the main reason why I offered JavaScript solution in the first place. In practice it realy does not matter. Any solution that will show the question as a machine-readable text can be easily solved and bypassed. More secure way is to use an image verification, ie captcha, and place the question as obfuscated text inside image.

Comment: I'll test your answer, I really would rather be using PHP for this, but I do appreciate your answer and maybe I'll find a use for it =)

Comment: My friend, your answer doesn't technically solve the question, but it does solve the problem and it actually goes beyond that and only allows the form to be processed if the answer it right! The only problem is that a computer with a bot could just turn off JS and have their way with it haha. I'm going to go ahead and give you the big green check though!

Comment: The only thing I ask of you is if you could add that when the submit button is clicked and the result is returned as error that .error class will be added to the <label> =)

Comment: As a client side solution of course that can be bypassed in many ways. I will write the server side solution also, maybe tomorrow, now I have no time.

Comment: I'm grateful for this as it is, if you can provide that as well later on then that would be even more amazing - how long have you been practicing? For now I just need to throw in something surrounding "if false addclass .error to label", I can probably figure it out though but whenever you have time to play with it!

Comment: @mattroberts33, I updated the answer, now js will add class .error to label if submit is invalid.

Comment: Fair enough (to your PHP answer haha) =)

Comment: Hello @Danijel I've updated my question with a couple lines of html from a slightly different set up and I'd like to use the code you gave me with this. The only thing I think needs to be changed is the line that adds .error class to <label>, right now it adds it to the parent of <input>, is there any way you could modify that line so it adds it to <label> directly, instead of just whatever the parent is? I promise I won't bug you after this haha, you've been great!

Comment: @mattroberts33. Usually labels are bound to an input element by using "for" attribute, so you can put `for="human-f"` attribute inside label and use `document.querySelector( "label[for='human-f']" ).setAttribute( "class", 'error' );` ( `querySelector` is not supported in IE<8). Or, since you have put the id attribute in label just use `getElementById` like `document.getElementById( 'question-label' ).setAttribute( "class", 'error' );`

Answer (score 1):

Try this (make sure you have session_start() at the top of the page) :

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['numbers'] = array(rand(2,9),rand(2,9));
$question = 'What is '.$_SESSION['numbers'][0].' + '.$_SESSION['numbers'][1].' ?';
$error = 0;
$error_msg = 'Wrong answer!';
if(isset($_POST)) {
   $correct_answer = $_SESSION['numbers'][0] + $_SESSION['numbers'][1];
   if(intval(trim($_POST['human'])) != $correct_answer) {
      $error = 1;
   }
}
?>
<label><?php echo $question; ?><input type="text" name="human" id="human" placeholder="What is it?" value="<?php echo (($error == 1) ? $error_msg : ''); ?>" /></label>
```

Comment: I like this so far, sorry I saw your answer earlier but I was out, any ways I'm about to test this - is there any way we can echo "Wrong answer!" in the input box itself or make the question text turn red? I don't have any room for text to appear (good for testing purposes though of course)

Comment: It seems to always say "Wrong answer!". I really like this solution so far though, just gotta get it working!

Comment: Made a few modifications.

Comment: This actually caused an Internal Server Error, not sure what happened, I tried a few things out but as long as that 'if' statement is on the page there is an Internal Server Error. Any ideas?

Comment: Okay nevermind I don't want it to say anything at all then if it isn't right, it's not what I thought it would be and it's not worth the time figuring out haha, how do I stop the form from being submitted if this answer isn't right though?

Comment: I don't know how to write this and you are the expert here my friend, I'm just doing some thinking: We need to have a variable called $answer that is false by default but when the submit button is pressed it will either stay false by default or it will come to true if the value of the input is correct and allow for the form to be processed. Either that or it will present a value of 1 and a JS script can see that and enable the form or else add a class to the label to make the text red so it only happens after.